# Best way to export nvarchar(max) data with line breaks?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still yet to find a reasonable solution to this problem. I need to export a table which has two columns with nvarchar(max) data. The data will have new lines, line breaks and sometimes Unicode characters, so a flat file format doesn't make much sense.

What is the optimal way to achieve this task? I have previously attempted it in C#, but the time taken to do the job was too slow. I am open to solutions in any reasonable domain, i.e. SQL Management Studio, C#, Powershell etc.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to move the table data to flat file?

Comment: Yeah ideally, or another solution would be to save the nvarchar(max) columns as text files, and then have a column in the flat file with a path to the text file.

Comment: Try using SSIS-Sql Server Integration services.

Comment: Have you tried the `bcp` utility - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-unicode-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server ? Did it work?

Comment: I have previously used replace to get around format limitations for quick & dirty. eg replace(replace(replace([ColumnName],char(10),'\n'),char(13),'\r'),char(8),'\t') and just swap them back on the other end.